# Object.assign Babel with external npm dep

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

I have an external NPM dependency that uses Object.assign. I want to use Babel, to assure compatibility with old browsers, either transforming Object.assign via helper or substituting it using another method, but it is not working.

PS: I can use a polyfill at the top of the code, i want to avoid this since it is a library (https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-assign/)

The dependency is : https://github.com/krux/postscribe 
via `var postscribe = require('postscribe');`

my .babelrc conf:

```
{
  "presets": [
     ["env", {
         "targets": {
            "browsers": ["Android 4", "iOS 7"]
         }
     }]
],
  "plugins": ["transform-object-assign"]
}
```

Gulp conf:

```
gulp.task('adtag', function () {
// set up the browserify instance on a task basis
var b = browserify({
    entries: './src/adtag/main.js',
    debug: true
}).transform(babelify)

return b.bundle()
    .pipe(source('smaatoAdTag.min.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({
        loadMaps: true
    }))
    // Add transformation tasks to the pipeline here.
    .pipe(uglify())
    .on('error', gutil.log)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/adtag/'));
});
```

Is there any way to substitute Object.assign if is in a dependency and not in the main code?

Comment: what is the dependency and how is it loaded?

Comment: I have updated the issue with the info. Thanks!

Comment: Use the polyfill if this is the only code you're concerned about https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: I rather skip the polyfill if gulp + babelify can transform my code or append the polyfill automatically

Comment: @ayxos that's a great rule of thumb, but `Object.assign` can be reliably polyfilled to es5 (ie 9+) in less than 5 LoC. Just write a polyfill in your code. You could copy/paste it into every file in your bundle without significantly increasing your payload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the docs for [babelify](https://github.com/babel/babelify#why-arent-files-in-node_modules-being-transformed)

You could use :

```
browserify().transform("babelify", {
  global: true,
  ignore: /\/node_modules\/(?!postscribe\/)/
});
```